# When Airplane mode is on telephonyManager.getSimOperatorName() returns null

Tags: android

When Airplane mode is on, `telephonyManager.getSimOperatorName()` returns `null`, even when the SIM card is present. Any alternate way to get `getSimOperatorName` when Airplane mode is on?

Comment: You can't.  Notice the documentation for that function:  Availability: SIM state must be SIM_STATE_READY.  Android doesn't read the SIM unless the radio is on and ready to transmit.

Comment: I have found something on stackoverflow                               getResources().getConfiguration().mcc is not empty in airplane mode

Comment: But is that true in all cases, or only if the phone was not in airplane mode when the app started?  Unsure, haven't tried it.

Comment: When phone restart and in flight mode it returns 0.